# Applications of microtransport protocol?

Tags: protocols

I want to know real time application of micro transport protocol in networks. What are exact applications of micro transport (µTP) protocol?

Comment: You mean that you want to find an application

Comment: i mean, where is using this protocol?

Comment: Most of uses in `µTorrent`, But just a look at [Micro Transport Protocol in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol)

Comment: yes, i already refereed, but i can't able to those bulk information take in my mind. so i need , some short and exact applications.. thanks @shA.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some about Micro Torrent Protocol:

The motivation for `uTP` is for `BitTorrent` clients to not disrupt internet connections, while still utilizing the unused bandwidth fully.

The problem is that DSL and cable modems typically have a send buffer disproportional to their max send rate, which can hold several seconds worth of packets. BitTorrent traffic is typically background transfers, and should have lower priority than checking email, phone calls and browsing the web, but when using regular TCP connections BitTorrent quickly fills up the send buffer, adding multiple seconds delay to all interactive traffic.

The fact that `BitTorrent` uses multiple TCP connections gives it an unfair advantage when competing with other services for bandwidth, which exaggerates the effect of BitTorrent filling the upload pipe. The reason for this is because TCP distributes the available bandwidth evenly across connections, and the more connections one application uses, the larger share of the bandwidth it gets.

And more in http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html